# Is "insisting on" followed by a statement acceptable?

Tags: grammaticality, usage

Can I say this?

> I insisted on that the event was a turkey.

I know that we say: somebody insists *on* something.

But I didn't know before yesterday that we can say: somebody insists *that*.

So is it common or correct to say: insist on that?

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly not common, as [this NGram shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=insisted+that%2C+insisted+on+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2019):

[image]

If the 'object' being insisted is a statement, you drop the on:

> I insisted that the event was a turkey.